# Functional promise using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-events

I am trying to download some data from a Phoenix web app and render the data on the front-end. For this I have the request and callback in a list and am running a list.reduce against it while `then`ing each request.

```
var Database = function() {
  this.reservations = [];
  this.applications = [];
  this.environments = [];
};

var database = new Database();

var requests = [$.getJSON('/api/applications', data => { database.applications = data }),
                $.getJSON('/api/environments', data => { database.environments = data }),
                $.getJSON('/api/reservations', data => { database.reservations = data })];

function run() {
  requests.reduce(function(chain, callback) {
      return (chain ? chain.then(callback) : callback);
  }, null).then(() => render(database));
}
```

However, this works most of the time in latest version of Google Chrome and maybe 10% of the times in Safari.

When I inspect the "database" after stepping into the render function, I see list of applications, but not environments and reservations (2 pieces of data).

**Edit:** Okay, so it works in Google Chrome in normal mode. But does not work all the time in incognito mode. In Safari it sometimes fetches all 3 pieces of data, and sometimes just 2 pieces of data. My application does not use any sessions.

I am guessing this is caused by the nature of $.ajax being asynchronous and perhaps I broke my promises. But I have hit a roadblock.

Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to chain your promises, they can all be requested at the same time since it doesn't look like any of them rely on each other. Instead, you can use a `.map()` and take the result, which will be a list of promises, and use an `.all()` to wait for them all to resolve.

*(I'm taking some liberties so the following should be considered pseudo-code)*

```
var urls = ['whatever.com', 'example.com/something', 'something.com/whatever'];

var requestPromises = urls.map(function(url) {
    return ajax(url); // assume ajax() returns a promise
});

Promise.all(requestPromises).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: wouldn't you just `Promise.all(requests).then(() => render(database));` - seeing as requests is an array of promises - no need for the map at all

Comment: Yes, you're right. I missed the `$.getJSON()` calls and thought they were just data objects that were going to be used to make requests.

Comment: Marking this as an answer, as it provided me the insight in fixing my problem although I fixed it following a little bit different approach. @Soviut

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more demonstrative of what I was assuming. showing the mapping of multiple ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Soviut for your help. For closure: here's what I did to fix this problem.

```
// ... is the ES6 spread operator
function run() { 
  $.when(...requests).then(() => {
    render(database);
  });
}
```